# Dealing with sequential/ordered data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I apologize if this question has already been asked, attempted a search but could not find a relevant thread.

I have been given a semi-large data source (~15m records) which I need to perform some analysis on to determine user behavior. The data source includes fields for the User ID, date of the transaction, and a flag to indicate if the transaction had a certain characteristic. Obviously I'm simplifying here to get to the core of the question. The number of transactions by user will vary quite a bit (from 1 to 200+), the date distribution will vary, and the distribution of flags will vary.

Consider the following table:

```
ID          User ID         Date             Flag
1           1               2015-01-03       Y
2           1               2015-03-15       N
3           1               2015-07-20       N
4           1               2015-11-18       N
5           1               2015-11-29       N
6           2               2015-02-16       Y
7           2               2015-03-03       N
8           2               2015-06-10       Y
9           2               2015-08-10       Y
```

How would one go about querying this data to isolate records based upon the characteristics of other records for the same user before or after?

For example:

1. How would one identify records with a 'Y' flag which are followed by three other records (ordered by date) for the same User ID with an 'N' flag? [Would return 1 in the above table]
2. How would one identify User IDs where 50% or more of their transactions with 'Y' flags occur in the first 20% of their transactions? [Would return User ID 1 in the above table]

I hope the question is clear enough.

***Edit:** The answer below is correct, however he did not know that I am using MySQL as the database (I added in the tag after he answered). MySQL DOES NOT support these functions, either Oracle or SQL Server would be able to implement these functions.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question assumes a reasonable database that supports window/analytic functions.

The first question can be handled using `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(flag, 1) over (partition by userid order by date) as flag_1,
             lead(flag, 2) over (partition by userid order by date) as flag_2,
             lead(flag, 3) over (partition by userid order by date) as flag_3
      from t
     ) t
where flag = 'Y' and flag_1 = 'N' and flag_2 = 'N' and flag_3 = 'N';
```

The second also uses window functions:

```
select user_id
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by user_id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
group by user_id
having sum(case when flag = 'Y' and seqnum/0.2 <= cnt then 1 else 0 end) >=
           0.5 * sum(case when flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end);
```

So, the answer to your question is basically:  Learn about window (analytic) functions.

Comment: Very interesting, I haven't seen these functions before but reading through the SQL I can kind of see what they must be doing. The database is MySQL and after a quick Google search it seems that I'll have no problem implementing this. Really appreciate the quick and detailed reply.